# SQL Server 2008 Time Datatype is in decimal need in Time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, time, decimal

I am getting stuck on something in my view.  There is a field that is being imported from a program and while it displays the time (military) the field itself is listed as a decimal datatype.  So, the field shows a decimal with it.  For example

timearrival

730.00000000

1000.00000000

1530.00000000

I would like to convert this to a time field, but I am getting errors like

"Explicit conversion from data type decimal to time is not allowed."

Does anyone know a quick way that I can take this field and have it display as 'HH:MM' and keep it in Military format as well?

Thanks for your help!

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the constant with your column name. Basically, treat it as it's coming in, where the string value is a time value. Slice the decimal, then stuff and cast.

```
select cast(stuff(replace(str(730.000000,4,0), ' ', '0'), 3,0,':') as time)
```